# How do I select all columns excluding one (or two) from a datatable in python

Tags: python, r, data.table, py-datatable

In [R data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), I can exclude columns like so

```
library(data.table)

foo <- data.table(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4, 5, 6), z = c(7, 8, 9))
print(foo)
   x y z
1: 1 4 7
2: 2 5 8
3: 3 6 9

# exclude one column
foo[, !"x"]
   y z
1: 4 7
2: 5 8
3: 6 9

# exclude two columns
foo[, !c("x", "y")]
   z
1: 7
2: 8
3: 9
```

How do I do the same thing in [Python datatable](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable)?

```py
import datatable as dt # v 1.0.0

foo = dt.Frame({'x': [1,2,3], 'y': [4,5,6], 'z': [7,8,9]})
print(foo)
   |     x      y      z
   | int32  int32  int32
-- + -----  -----  -----
 0 |     1      4      7
 1 |     2      5      8
 2 |     3      6      9
[3 rows x 3 columns]

# exclude one column
foo[:, !"x"]    # error
foo[:, !["x"]]  # error
foo[:, !f.x]    # error

# exclude two columns
```

## EDIT

Apologies for not explicitly stating this, but I'm aware of the obvious solution - do an inclusion statement, whereby I build a list of all the columns I want to include and use that as opposed to an exclusion statement whereby I use a list of columns to exclude. However, I find the inclusion technique awkward / cumbersome and less natural to read and write. As such, I'm specifically seeking an exclusion solution, like the one implemented in `data.table`.

Comment: Python does not have a list exclusion operator. You've received basically all recommendations from the [official documentation](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/select_and_filter_data.html#deselect-rows-columns) on how to perform this operation. If you wanted to you could define a `c` function yourself which hides the comprehension or filtering.

Comment: You can use `remove` : ``foo[:, f[:].remove(f['x', 'y'])]``. All the other options work fine and are more robust than `remove`/`extend` -> these functions are only available for the columns. It doesnt cost to put the list comprehension in a variable and pass into the datatable brackets, in my opinion

Answer (score 4):

These methods are listed in the documentation on how to [Deselect rows/columns](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/select_and_filter_data.html#deselect-rows-columns).

#### List Building Methods

A comprehension on [`names`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame/names.html) to filter out values:

```py
cols = ["x"]
foo_filtered = foo[:, [name for name in foo.names if name not in cols]]
```

Or the `filter` equivalent:

```py
cols = ["x"]
foo_filtered = foo[:, list(filter(lambda n: n not in cols, foo.names))]
```

---

With a list of booleans:

```py
cols = ["x"]
foo_filtered = foo[:, [n not in cols for n in foo.names]]
```

or the `map` equivalent:

```py
cols = ["x"]
foo_filtered = foo[:, list(map(lambda n: n not in cols, foo.names))]
```

---

`foo_filtered`:

```
   |     y      z
   | int32  int32
-- + -----  -----
 0 |     4      7
 1 |     5      8
 2 |     6      9
[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

#### Exclusion Method

[`remove`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/fexpr/remove.html) can also be used, however, this is limited to column selection:

```py
from datatable import f


foo[:, f[:].remove(f['x', 'y'])]
```

```
   |     z
   | int32
-- + -----
 0 |     7
 1 |     8
 2 |     9
[3 rows x 1 column]
```

---

This method does not come from the documentation.

#### Sub-Class Method

If obscuring the list comprehension is the goal, we can make a wrapper for `tuple` that can be used to add additional behaviour to `names`. Namely, using `xor` (or other desired operation) to become the "exclusion operator".

(I've chosen `xor` because `pandas` columns used to allow this operator to exclude columns.)

This custom `tuple` can then be used with a sub-class of `dt.Frame` to wrap the property [`names`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame/names.html):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import datatable as dt  # v 1.0.0


class TableColumns(tuple):
    def __xor__(self, other) -> TableColumns:
        if isinstance(other, str):
            output = [n != other for n in self]
        elif any(isinstance(other, i) for i in [tuple, list, set]):
            output = [n not in other for n in self]
        else:
            raise TypeError(
                f'Unsupported type {type(other)} used to filter names'
            )
        return TableColumns(output)


class MyFrame(dt.Frame):
    @property
    def names(self) -> TableColumns:
        return TableColumns(super(MyFrame, self).names)
```

Then filtering can be done naturally:

Frame Constructor (Using Sub-Class):

```py
foo = MyFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6], 'z': [7, 8, 9]})
```

Filtering With `List`:

```py
foo_filtered = foo[:, foo.names ^ ['x', 'z']]
```

`Tuple`:

```py
foo_filtered = foo[:, foo.names ^ ('x', 'z')]
```

`Set`:

```py
foo_filtered = foo[:, foo.names ^ {'x', 'z'}]
```

`foo_filtered`:

```
   |     y
   | int32
-- + -----
 0 |     4
 1 |     5
 2 |     6
[3 rows x 1 column]
```

Excluding a single column with `str`:

```py
foo_filtered = foo[:, foo.names ^ 'x']
```

```
   |     y      z
   | int32  int32
-- + -----  -----
 0 |     4      7
 1 |     5      8
 2 |     6      9
[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: apologies, added another option to your answer

Comment: No apologies necessary. You know where the documentation is for `remove`?

Comment: i wrote the docs, so I should know :) . it is [here](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/select_and_filter_data.html#deselect-rows-columns) and scroll down; it is listed as part of the options

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I missed it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using list comprehensions:

```
>>> cols_to_exclude = ['x']
>>> print(foo[:, [col for col in foo.names if col not in cols_to_exclude]])
   |     z      y
   | int32  int32
-- + -----  -----
 0 |     7      4
 1 |     8      5
 2 |     9      6
[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select data [using booleans](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/select_and_filter_data.html#via-booleans) in datatable, so a list comprehension to generate the desired booleans for the column slection can be done.

In this case that would be `foo[:, ["x" not in name for name in foo.names]]`

```py
>>> import datatable as dt
>>> foo = dt.Frame({'x': [1,2,3], 'y': [4,5,6], 'z': [7,8,9]})
>>> foo[:, ["x" not in name for name in foo.names]]
   |     y      z
   | int32  int32
-- + -----  -----
 0 |     4      7
 1 |     5      8
 2 |     6      9
[3 rows x 2 columns]
```